# Xcode 15 Linked Error with UnityFramework and Firebase Integration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm developing an iOS app by integrating a Unity project, However, I am consistently facing errors in the UnityFramework each time I build.

**- Unity Editor Version: 2022.3.10f1

- Firebase SDK Version: 11.6.0
- Xcode Version: 15.01**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E05wq.jpg)

The issue appears to be connected to Firebase.
If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to address this, your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which Firebase SDK are you using? The SDK for Unity or the SDK for iOS? How are you managing dependencies? If you are using the SDK for Unity, what version of the [EDM4U](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) are you using?